# Animation for dragging a UIButton in between two other UIButton in a Collection View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uicollectionview

I am trying to make an app where I have a UICollectionView of UIButtons, and I want to take another UIButton from the bottom of my screen, drag it in between any other two buttons, and have them separate to make room for the new button in case the user wants to drop it in there. So far, I have been able to make my button dragable using UIPanGestureRecognizer, but haven't gone much further than that. Any suggestions or help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout)? That does exactly what you're describing.